React app not getting created using npx command
I have installed Node.Js and tried creating react app using npx command in powershell and VSCode terminal its not getting created. Does anyone have any solution?
PS C:\Users\bidar\Downloads\React> npx create-react-app my-app
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\bidar\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\bidar\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent

I tried re-installing Node.Js and running the command again its not working and tried clearing the cache but still the same.

Your directory C:\Users\bidar\AppData\Roaming\npm is missing
Try to  Run your terminal as administrator
then uninstall npm
npm uninstall -g npm

clear cache
npm cache clean --force

Then install again
npm install -g npm

Or you can manually create it
Go to the directory C:\Users\bidar\AppData\Roaming and create a folder "npm"

Thank you for the suggestion its working

You are welcome @AchuthaBidarahalli
